# Wiki site for consumer medical device feature comparison tables?

Tags: medical

With the increased marketing of sophisticated medical devices to consumers, it would seem that a central repository for public, wiki-based feature comparison tables would be a big help.

But AFAICS, no such tables exist as a public wiki that could be maintained as new technologies appeared. Those tables that do compare devices (e.g., for diabetes, sleep apnea) seem to be non-wiki, not current, and hosted on sites specific to particular conditions.

As a first cut design, each wiki page would be dedicated to a product category, with a table indicating brand, model, features relevant to the product category, links to reviews, links to manuals.

The site would also serve as a repository for manuals not available elsewhere online.

So, I’m raising the topic here to prompt discussion of the merits, hosting possibilities, etc.

Thoughts, anyone?